# How do i make spring boot jpa operations wait for each other

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two JPA operations in my class. patient save and phone save operations. I want phone to save after patient has been saved. The operations seem to be happening at the time. The patient is saved successfully but the phoneService.addPatientPhone(phone, patientId); is never excecuted even if patientResolver.getPhone() containts numbers.

```
**Service class**
public Patient createPatient(PatientResolverDTO patientResolver, String patientId) throws Exception {
        Patient checkExist = patientRepository.findByPatientId(patientId);

        Patient patient = new Patient();

        if (checkExist != null) {
            log.debug("Patient already exit: {}", request);
            return request;
        } else {

            patient.setPatientId(patientId);
            patient.setFirstname(patientResolver.getFirstname());
            patient.setLastname(patientResolver.getLastname());
            patient.setDob(patientResolver.getBirthdate());

            Patient savedPatient = patientRepository.save(patient);

            /**
             * If the payload containts phone(s). Add the phone number(s) to the
             * patient Phone
             */

            if (patientResolver.getPhone() != null && savedPatient != null) {
                for (PatientResolverPhone phone : patientResolver.getPhone()) {
                    phoneService.addPatientPhone(phone, patientId);
                }
            }

            
            return savedPatient;
        }
    }
```

```
**Repository class**


/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the {@link Patient} entity.
 */
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Long> {

    Patient findOneByPatientId(String patientId);

    Patient findByPatientId(String patientId);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are using `Long` instead of `String` on your Repository:

   `public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, String>`
2. Have you checked on your database if the number is added? If yes the problem is that you are returning the saved patient without the updated information in this line:

   `Patient savedPatient = patientRepository.save(patient);`
3. If you wanto to return the patient with the updated info you need to retrieve the patient again or set the phone to te object that you already have created

   `PatientResolverPhone prf = phoneService.addPatientPhone(phone, patientId);
   savedPatient.setPatientResolverPhone(prf);
   return savedPatient;`